# PHP Stripe API error on adding new card

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

im trying to add a new card to an existing customer and getting an error that i dont understand why it happens. here is a sample of the  code:

```html
$strp_customer  = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer['stripe_id']);

echo $strp_customer->id;
echo "<br>";
echo $_POST['stripeToken'];
echo "<br>";
echo $strp_customer->default_source;
echo "<br>";
//save card to the customer in stripe
$strp_customer->source->create(array("source" => $_POST['stripeToken']));

echo $strp_customer->default_source;
```

the line with source create give me "Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on null"

but all echo return proper information. so the customer is retrieved and stripeToken is there. what can possibly cause that error?

Comment: Whats the output of `var_dump($strp_customer->source)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is a typo. The code should be

```
$strp_customer->sources->create(array("source" => $_POST['stripeToken']));
```

It's `sources` and not `source`. You also need to make sure that you're on a recent version of the PHP library to support this call.

This will add a new card to the customer but won't set it as the default source. You're also not retrieving the customer again so you'd print the same value as before.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with card details.

```
try {
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve('cus_xxxxxxxxxxx');
        $card = $customer->sources->create(
            array(
                "source" => [
                    "object" => "card",
                    "name" => 'card holder name',
                    "number" => 'card number',
                    "cvc" => 'cvc',
                    "exp_month" => 'exp month',// E.g: 01,02...12
                    "exp_year" => 'exp year' // exp year
                ]
            )
        );
        echo ('Your card has been added successfully!');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo ('Unable to add new card, please enter valid card details.');
    }
```